# Typescript types: use static readonly/const property of generic type in type definition

Tags: typescript, generics, types, type-conversion

I have this class definition:

```js
export class Entity {
    a?: string;
    b?: string;
    c?: string;
    static required = ['c'] as const;
}
```

Basically I want to write a type definition which will take this type, and use the static **array** `required`, to generate the type in which `c` is not optional.

I wanted to do this:

```js
export type WithRequired<T extends Entity> = Partial<T> & Required<Pick<T, typeof T.required[number]>>;
```

But this fails with the error:

```
'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

If I slightly change the definition by replacing `T.required` with `Entity.required`, then it does not give me an error:

```js
export type WithRequired<T extends Entity> = Partial<T> & Required<Pick<T, typeof Entity.required[number]>>;
```

Which works in this case.. but this is of course not a satisfactory solution, because I'd have to create a type for each variation of "Entity" in the project, instead of having 1 generic type to handle all cases.

So I actually have 2 questions, and having just 1 of them answered would help me a ton:

- Is there a way to "Require" properties of a class based on a static const array of that same class?
- Is there a way to change the part around `T.required`, so that typescript stops throwing errors at me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *type* `Entity` is the type of instances of your class. The *value* `Entity` the constructor of the class, and `typeof Entity` is the type of that constructor.

And the type of instances is *completely* disconnected from the type of its constructor. So if you have only the instance type, you cannot know the type of the constructor.

In fact, you can use a classes instance type as you would any interface, which is proof that the instance type has no idea about what constructed it.

```
class Foo { bar: string }
const foo: Foo = { bar: 'baz' } // works
```

---

However, you can go the other direction and derive the instance type from the constructor type with `InstanceType<typeof MyClass>`.

That means that you must capture the *constructor* type as the generic, since that's where your static value actually is. You can then pull the `required` static property form that type and merge it into the instance type.

```
export type WithRequired<T extends typeof Entity> =
    Partial<InstanceType<T>> &
    Required<Pick<InstanceType<T>, T['required'][number]>>;
```

And use like so:

```
type TestA = WithRequired<typeof Entity>
const testA1: TestA = { c: 'c'} // works
const testA2: TestA = { a: 'a' } // Property 'c' is missing in type '{ a: string; }' but required in type 'Required<Pick<Entity, "c">>'.(2322)
```

The downside is you have to pass in `typeof MyClass` which is slightly more verbose. But if you want to access a static property then you need the type of the constructor, and there's no way you're going to get around that simple truth.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=143&pln=12&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4FEB2MCWMAnnAN4BQcVcKA-AFxxoxT44DmA3JdQEYNMWbLjyoIBzVh27VBKAgjhRgARwCu+ZQBM4AXjgBtAOQIjAXRqYEEHM24BfcuVCRYcYmGBwA6oQAWAEqqGtoAPAAqcKAwwDhamB7AEABm2HiERAB8euQAkAAKKLD4KEihAJK2MCg4CMDhRJ4RmdkAZHlB6prAWqH5+AgA1hVVNXUNTeGZADRw4cbKXdrmBjhqALa8wFBmLdzkiXPAzACCej7+nSE9oYkpaQTEmeTWVe7HMCcAjIzhH2f6UiIRgmIz2OAAeghcAA7tBBmgXjZmO9TgAmX7-c5AlAglBGODgqFwfJQCCeWAkUFwfCYda0tDCGk4dyNLxGHGMSTCTiEgm8NTwRbXHRsVmeOBGK7dXr9IahXCPIizABECBVLSMADoABRogDMaLRAEpyEA)